# Want save the file in to database using ajax in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I want to save the file and notes in backend using ajax in django. For file i am getting trouble.
How to send the file to backend.
Notes i am getting to view
but i am not able to send file to view.

```
<form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="nofilesforms"> 

<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file_data">
<textarea class="form-control notesdata" data-stylesheet-url="" name="notes"></textarea>
<button  class="btn btn-primary" id="filesandnotes" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

$(document).on('click','#filesandnotes',function(){


                                var notes = $('.notesdata').val();
                                var path = $('input[type=file][name=image_file]').val();
                                alert(path);

                            var data = {

                                        notes:notes,
                                        path:path


                                        };

                                $.ajax({
                                    url:"/cbs/msw1/",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: data,
                                    success: function (response) {



                                                    },
                                        error: function () {
                                                        }
                                });
                            });
```

Please anyone can guide me for this. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: "i am getting in backend" What on earth does that mean? Also, you should provide more information about the diagnosing you've already done on your code. Otherwise, this is a "hunt for the bugs" question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to bind on `submit` of the form itself and not the `click` event, prevent the default submit, get the file data (filename, filesize, blob, etc.) here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to the `File` API, also the file input can hold multiple files, so you have to loop on the array of `Files`. After that you send an AJAX request to your Django backend. And check it and do whatever you want. You also can use JS to check your form, but always check on the backend !

Answer (score 0):

You'd better try this:

```
$('#nofilesforms').submit(function(event) { ... });
```

Also, you may like to use a jQuery File Upload plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously